# Limiting function to drawing only once when clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click event that needs to run a function only once, but what I have is propagating each time I click the mouse.  I know that it's because the event is looking for each time the images on the canvas is clicked, but how do I make it to only detect one click event to run this particular function?  Do I need to make an entirely separate click event?

```
$("#schematic_holder").on("click", function(ev){
    var x = ev.pageX;
    var y = ev.pageY;
    for(var img in images){
        var img_x = images[img].dest_x;
        var img_y = images[img].dest_y;
        var img_w = images[img].width;
        var img_h = images[img].height;
        if((x > img_x) && (x < img_x + img_w)){
            if((y > img_y) && (y < img_y + img_h)){
```

This is the function I want to call only once but have basically created an infinite loop, which is something I don't want.

```
                if(images[img].name == "Landing Gear Handle"){
                    drawImages(images[img].src, images[img].name, images[img].position_2.x, images[img].position_2.y, images[img].width, images[img].height, images[img].position_2.dest_x, images[img].position_2.dest_y, images[img].width, images[img].height, images[img].position_2.scale_x, images[img].position_2.scale_y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: You could add a boolean that is initially false, check if the boolean is false in your click handler. If it is false then run your function and set it to true. Else return.

Comment: If you want handler function to be called just once, use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of `.on()`.

Comment: @bhspencer I was thinking about doing that, but hoping there would be a different way.  This way's probably the easiest and best way though.

Comment: @Frax, That would work, but this particular click event doesn't only need to be done once and it has other purposes, but it only needs to call the `drawImages()` function once.  I guess I could just duplicate the click event and have one set to be `.on()` and the other to `.one()`.

Comment: @bhspencer, I went with your solution.  If you'd like, make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Then call `$("#schematic_holder").off("click")`, when drawing. If you have more click handlers on that element, define function under name, so that you can call something like `.off(handlerFunction)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add a boolean that is initially false, check if the boolean is false in your click handler. If it is false then run your function and set it to true. Else return.